# Vue - How to import components dynamically

Tags: vue.js

So I will have an array for X length. I have no clue how many components will be included. How do I import them, can I loop over the array and import them, or use v-bind:is?

Any help is welcome!

Thanks,
Justin.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <component v-for="(componentName, index) in this.components" v-bind:is="componentName" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  // Import just the ones I need
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please see [Async Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can include an `i` when you have no idea how many will be included

```
<component v-for="i in this.components" v-bind:is="componentName" />
  </div>
```

then for the js

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: function() {
    return {
    this: {id: 1, name: ''}
}
}
```

Comment: The issue still comes with not being able to import the components...